# Angular 9- Json pipe does not display the decimal value

Tags: html, css, angular, pipe, less

I have a json value something like this

```
this.data = {"eoiStatistics": [
{
  "dateRange": {
    "explicitStartDate": "1997-01-01T00:00:00",
    "explicitEndDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00"
  },
  "outstandingApplicationCount": 0.0,
  "pendingApplicationCount": 24.0,
  "approvedApplicationCount": 0.0,
  "declinedApplicationCount": 0.0,
  "closedApplicationCount": 0.0 }]}
```

When i display this with a json pipe `{{data | json}}` in the application it displays like this

```
{"eoiStatistics": [
{
  "dateRange": {
    "explicitStartDate": "1997-01-01T00:00:00",
    "explicitEndDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00"
  },
  "outstandingApplicationCount": 0,
  "pendingApplicationCount": 24,
  "approvedApplicationCount": 0,
  "declinedApplicationCount": 0,
  "closedApplicationCount": 0
}]}
```

So if my value is 24.0 it displays 24 , i know that the .0 has no value but I need to display it in my application. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to control this. You can however think of two workarounds. You can either manipulate the data being send, or change the way the data is displayed:

1. Change the json value to a string, instead of a number:

```
"pendingApplicationCount": "24.0"
```

2. Change the way it's displayed. Because you use angular, you can use the [`DecimalPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#decimalpipe) pipe

```
<div>{{ data.pendingApplicationCount | number: '1.1-5' }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @PoulKruijt, we could see the [`JsonPipe`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/json_pipe.ts) is a transform function with a single line.

```js
transform(value: any): string {
  return JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
}
```

So we could write a custom pipe with a `replacer` argument in the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'jsonDecimal'
})
export class JsonDecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, length?: number): any {
    return JSON.stringify(
      value, 
      (key: any, value: any) => {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return Number(value).toFixed(length);
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      }, 
      2);
  }

}
```

**Example 1**

You could then specify the number of decimal places you need to display in the template.

```html
<div>{{ data | jsonDecimal:1 }}</div>
```

will print numbers with a single decimal place

Template output

```
{ "eoiStatistics": [ { "dateRange": { "explicitStartDate": "1997-01-01T00:00:00", "explicitEndDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00" }, "outstandingApplicationCount": "0.0", "pendingApplicationCount": "24.0", "approvedApplicationCount": "0.0", "declinedApplicationCount": "0.0", "closedApplicationCount": "0.0" } ] }
```

**Example 2**

You could also specify more decimal numbers if you need to append more zeroes at the end.

```html
<div>{{ data | jsonDecimal:4 }}</div>
```

will print

```
{ "eoiStatistics": [ { "dateRange": { "explicitStartDate": "1997-01-01T00:00:00", "explicitEndDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00" }, "outstandingApplicationCount": "0.0000", "pendingApplicationCount": "24.0000", "approvedApplicationCount": "0.0000", "declinedApplicationCount": "0.0000", "closedApplicationCount": "0.0000" } ] }
```